# Sitecore Setup installation fails with error Failed to open XML file, system error:-2147024786

Tags: installation, sitecore, sitecore8

When running Sitecore Setup the following error pops up:

> Failed to open XML file, system error:-2147024786

[image: Sitecore Setup]

I've tried going through the `eventviewer` but to no avail.

Not unimportant is that I used the installer but forgot to change my rootdirectory. As a consequence I had to uninstall (using the same installer Sitecore). 
Now however it "feels" as though there are some references or remnants left behind somewhere. 
Who has a clue or can give me an idea of what is going on?

Comment: If you need quickest solution to install - use Sitecore Instance Manager - the one never fails! But of course, if that is applicable to your situation

Comment: Due to your low reputation you couldn't embed the image, I did it for you. I also added the error in the question body, the title should not be necessary to read to understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Kyll
Martin I'll try that , thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct, this issue is because the previous Sitecore instance, with the same name, has not been removed completely. You will need to manually complete the following tasks to remove the remnants and be able to run the installer, it has worked for me in past;

1. Stop the App Pool for the uninstalled site in IIS
2. Stop the Web Application for the uninstalled site in IIS
3. Perform an `iisreset` in command line
4. Delete the App Pool and Web app in IIS
5. You should now be able to completely delete the folder containing the `Website` and `Data` folder completely
6. If you are still having trouble deleting it check the folder's `Security Permissions`, the Users and their Permissions and Read Only checkbox. Ensure you have control to delete
7. Delete the relating entry in the `hosts` file
8. If you also installed Databases access them via MSSQL Management Studio, take all relating databases `Offline` then delete them.

This will effectively remove all remanants of the previous site. If what ever reason the issue still persists, Sitecore's own [Sitecore Instance Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/modules/sitecore_instance_manager.aspx) has a delete option which will completely uproot the site for you. Try installing with `SIM` then.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Sitecore installer also writes some stuff to the Windows Registry. I've had odd installer issues in the past where bits of registry data didn't get cleaned up properly. So if you're manually tidying up after a broken uninstall, RegEdit.exe can help. This blog post (while not really discussing this exact issue) has info on the registry path to look at: https://jermdavis.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/getting-over-enthusiastic-with-sims-delete-function/

Comment: Great post, I wasn't aware of the registry additions on install thanks for the info

Comment: Great you were spot on! I After step 5 I will definately look more into that instance manager. 
Thanks all.